# Calling a class from another class causes the sleeps to get skipped over

Tags: java, static, sleep

When I run the code in end() in its own class, everything works as expected.

Below is the overall class for this program. After running Buildings(), Shield(), Start(), and Almost all of Asteroid() perfectly the sleeps get skipped in the end() method.

```
import wheelsunh.users.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.*;
/** 
 * AsteroidApp.java:
 * Creates a frame 
 * @author Levi Poland


* Assignment Program 9
 */
public class AsteroidApp
{
    public static TextBox endText;
    /** General Constructor for the AsteroidApp class.
      * 
      */
    public AsteroidApp()
    {
        new Buildings();
        new Shield();
        new Start();
        new Asteroid();
    }
    public static void end()
    {
        endText = new TextBox();
        endText.setSize( 70, 30 );
        endText.setFillColor( Color.red );
        endText.setFrameColor( Color.red.darker() );
        endText.setLocation( 315, 170 );
        endText.setText( "You LOSE!" );
        Utilities.sleep(600);
        endText.setText( "You did manage to save the puny humans for " + 
        Asteroid.timeLasted + " seconds though.");
        Utilities.sleep(1000);
        while( endText.getYLocation() + endText.getHeight() > 0 )
        {
            Utilities.sleep(8);
            endText.setLocation( endText.getXLocation(),
                                      endText.getYLocation() - 1 );
        }
        System.out.println(endText.getLocation());
    }
    /** Main program creates a frame and an Asteroid App.
     *
     * @param args the command line.
     */
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Frame f1 = new Frame( 700, 400 );
        new AsteroidApp();
    }
}
```

How it's called in my Asteroid class

```
if( oneTime == 0 )
{
    AsteroidApp.end();
    oneTime = oneTime + 1;
}
```

The sleeps get skipped...

Comment: `static` is not your friend, it will do you a lot of harm if you don't use it carefully. The likely cause of your issue is probably a threading issue, but with out more context it's impossible to know. Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, most GUI frameworks aren't thread safe, so you might have issues going on

Comment: What package is `Utilities` a member of?

Comment: Utilities is from my university

Comment: static void - sleep(int m) - sleep for m milliseconds, ignore exceptions.